Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.FeatureNotSupportedException for PhoneDialer and EmailMessage
I am getting below exception for PhoneDialer and EmailMessage features.

Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.FeatureNotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Communication.PhoneDialerImplementation.ValidateOpen(String number) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Essentials\src\PhoneDialer\PhoneDialer.shared.cs:line 73
at Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Communication.PhoneDialerImplementation.Open(String number) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Essentials\src\PhoneDialer\PhoneDialer.android.cs:line 25
at NeedHelp.Pages.FriendDetailsPage.PhoneNumber_Tapped(Object sender, EventArgs args)

PhoneDialer.Open(phone);

var message = new EmailMessage
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    To = recipients
    Cc = ccRecipients,
    Bcc = bccRecipients
};
await Email.ComposeAsync(message);

Do we have any alternatives for these features in MAUI?

which platform are you testing, and are you using a physical device or en emulator?

@Jason Android and iOS platforms and I am using physical device

Please do the configurations on platform-specific setup as described in Phone dialer - .NET MAUI | Microsoft Learn and Email - .NET MAUI | Microsoft Learn.
